# Command `\arrowvert' already defined and Margin Suitability

Tags: amsmath, margins, unicode-math, xepersian

Unfortunately, I am no expert in LaTeX, however I have found myself coerced into using it again and again. My short term solution for the aforementioned deficiency thus far has been to search extensively on this site and whatever other references I could attain to produce the desired results by copying the code I have accosted. Therefore, it is not unexpected to run to several errors whilst doing so.
Hence, I pose to you two different issues if that is alright.

1. In trying to integrate *newtxmath* I come across the ensuing error and the result does not resemble what I know *newtxmath* looks like.

> Command `\arrowvert' already defined. ...\mathord}{symbols}{106}{largesymbols}{60}

2. I have copied the margins from the template of a Ph.D. thesis. Do you think it suits a book?

Finally, do you have any recommendations for the ordering of the integrated packages? Thanks for your attention in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{footnote}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\makesavenoteenv{algorithm}
\usepackage[top=40mm, bottom=40mm, left=25mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[perpagefootnote=on]{bidi}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.9]{Cambria}
\setmathdigitfont{XM Yekan}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{تعریف}[section]
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{قضیه}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{لم}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{مسئلهٔ}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{نتیجه}
\newtheorem{remark}[definition]{ملاحظه}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{مثال}
\doublespacing
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\begin{document}
    \include{c2}
    \include{c4}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{مراجع}
    \bibliographystyle{plain-fa}
    \bibliography{ch2refs}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't answer your questions, but may help you in other ways.  First, the math packages are better loaded in a different order.  `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so both aren't necessary.  And that is better loaded before `amsthm`, so: `\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}`.  Regarding page size, dissertations are usually set on larger pages than most books.  Think of your audience.  How many pages will your book have, and where will the reader be reading it?  Look at some similar books and how they fit on bookshelves.  Then decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The package `footnote` is obsolete and unmaintained. Don't use it.
2. It makes no sense to load both `unicode-math` and `newtxmath`.
3. `inputenc` is useless with XeLaTeX.
4. Fix the package loading order.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[top=40mm, bottom=40mm, left=25mm, right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[perpagefootnote=on]{bidi}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont[Scale=1]{Scheherazade}% I don't have XB Zar
\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.9]{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
%\setmathdigitfont{XM Yekan}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{تعریف}[section]
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{قضیه}
\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{لم}
\newtheorem{proposition}[definition]{مسئلهٔ}
\newtheorem{corollary}[definition]{نتیجه}
\newtheorem{remark}[definition]{ملاحظه}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{مثال}

\doublespacing
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % Why?

\begin{document}

تِهْران پرجمعیت‌ترین شهر و پایتخت ایران، مرکز استان تهران و شهرستان تهران است. این شهر در برآورد سال ۱۴۰۱ بالغ بر ۹٬۰۳۹٬۰۰۰ تن جمعیت داشته‌است و براساس برآورد سال ۲۰۱۸ سازمان ملل متحد، سی و چهارمین[۶][۷] شهر پرجمعیت جهان و پرجمعیت‌ترین شهر باختر آسیا می‌باشد. کلان‌شهر تهران نیز دومین کلان‌شهر پرجمعیت خاورمیانه است.

% text from https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/تهران

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I do not use footnote package, how can I produce footnotes in tabular and algorithm environments?

Comment: So, both unicode-math and newtxmath prdouce the same result?

Comment: @mali1234 Their working is different, but they fight each other in trying to set up the math fonts. About footnotes in floats, avoid them.

Comment: @mali1234 If you want to add footnotes to a table, use the options provided by the `tabularray` package. Read the manual especially chapter three onward how to do that. Basically the environments *talltblr* and *longtblr* offer you the option to include footnotes and remarks.

Comment: Isn't it better to load `amthm` after `mathtools`, as barbara mentioned?